# Unable to set basic auth security rules to FIRESTORE

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firebase-security

Im trying to set rules to Firestore allowing all user  to read and write around if they're signed in.

I already have my Authentication working with Firebase, using email and password.

But the simplest auth rule I write, it just throw me an error.

Im trying to make Firestore work with this rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
     }
   }
 }
```

But when I try to write to Firestore I got this:

[image: Error throw by Firestore when adding basic Auth Rules]

If I try the Function Helpers Approach:

```
 service cloud.firestore {
   //Function
   function isSignedIn() {
     return request.auth.uid != null;
 //Also tried with "request.auth != null"
   }
   //Rules
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read: if isSignedIn();
       allow write: if isSignedIn();
 //Also tried with "allow read, write: if isSignedIn();"
     }
   }
 }
```

It also throw me the same error.

I also tried matching custom paths, like `match /Restaurants/{RestaurantsId} ...`  but also didn’t work…

But if I remove everything and I use the following default rule:

```
 service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write;
     }
   }
 }
```

it does work…

I’ve followed Firestore Documentation, AngularFirebase Video Tutorial, looked at github and here to similar cases and I still cant make it work. I see everybody that has tried this got this working perfectly, but it does not with me :S.

**––––UPDATE 1––––**

Here is how Im calling the set method of Firestore:

When I press a “Save Button”  I call this helper function:

```
saveMealHandler() {
    const { mealImage, mealCategory, mealName, mealIngredients, mealPrice, mealOptions, mealExtras, user } = this.props;
    const id = this.props.completeMenu.length;
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.props.saveMeal({
      key: id,
      name: mealName,
      avatar: mealImage,
      ingredients: mealIngredients,
      price: mealPrice,
      category: mealCategory,
      options: mealOptions,
      extras: mealExtras
    }, user);
    this.props.cleanAllInputs();
  }
```

and this helper call’s the following action creator which writes on Firestore:

```
export const saveMeal = (newMeal, user) => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const docRef = db.collection('Resto').doc(user);
  return dispatch => {
    docRef.set({
        isWorking: 'JALAPEÑO!'
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Document successfully written!');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
    });
    dispatch({ type: SAVE_NEW_MEAL_TO_MENU, payload: newMeal });
  };
};
```

**––––UPDATE 1––––**

**––––UPDATE 2––––**

This is the function which capture the user and password and calls the action creator:

```
  onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.props;
    console.log(email, password);
    this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
  }
```

This is the action creator im using for register and login in an user

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_START });
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => userLoginSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(user => userLoginSuccess(dispatch, user))
          .catch(() => userLoginFail(dispatch));
      });
  };
};
//Helpers
const userLoginSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: user.uid });
};
const userLoginFail = (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL });
};
```

And this is how I know this functions are working:

[image]

**––––UPDATE 2––––**

With all my attempts I think may be I missed to install something without knowing in or there is something wrong when I add the condition. But It this moment I just prefer to ask.

I also recorded a video so you can see the issue, here it is:

https://youtu.be/9fmWk7-HjZ4

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Please edit your question to also include the minimum **code** that is needed to trigger the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for quick reply. Now I updated the question with the functions im using to write on Firestore. Thanks you so much for your consideration 

Comment: I don't see an immediate problem with the rules. How do you know that there is a signed in user?

Comment: What is the user property when the Promise fails in saveMeal? it should be a string. In console it looks like cleanAllInputs is executed prior to saveMeal.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated the question again. In **Update 2** I placed how I know the user is signed in. Also, you can check the video.

Comment: @TroelsLenda I passed the user as argument to try what you asked and this is what I got. I made this: 

`.catch((error) => {
        console.error('user is: ', user, 'Error writing document: ', error);` 


I got the user ID as a string as you suggest It should happen...

`user is:  Gs9ltlXk6DOlCnouPQqRi69UFkM2 Error writing document:  Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

i came across same problem

import all firebase cdn below

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-app.js

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-auth.js

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-firestore.js